# Managing floats when there is not much text

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a section in my document where I discuss results of my simulation, pictured as graphs, which in turn are included as floating images in the document. However, $\latex$ seems to put only one floating picture per page, which causes most of the images to float all over references, and hence matching pictures with text is rather difficult.

How can I manage this situation? I would still like to benefit from all the automatic positioning of floats, I just want more of them on one page.

The floats are included like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
%\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{CVaR_vs_xi}
\caption{\label{f9}CVaR for different values of project volatility ($\xi$), expressed as a fraction of the initial loan amount.}
%\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You should read the section titled **Details on the parameters that restrict/influence the placement** in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31)

Comment: In addition to Werner's comment, you can put more than one image in a `figure` environment...